# Handling the default button when ownerdraw button is present

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc

My ownerdraw class does not properly assign the default button.

In the example below, there is a standard default button and an ownerdraw button. The default button is highlighted when dialog starts. When I click the ownerdraw button, the ownerdraw is highlighted, but the default button does not lose highlight.

Screen shot immediately after ownerdraw button is clicked once:
[image: Dialog, ownerdraw, default button]

---

It works fine when I click the buttons once more. Then it shows only one default button.

It works fine if I override `WM_PAINT` instead of `WM_DRAWITEM`. It works fine if there is no edit control present.

But the code below doesn't handle the highlight correctly when the dialog starts.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <Uxtheme.h>
#include <vssym32.h>
#include "Resource.h"

#pragma comment(lib, "Uxtheme.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "ComCtl32.lib")

LRESULT CALLBACK ButtonProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, UINT_PTR uIdSubClass, DWORD_PTR)
{
    switch(msg)
    {
    case WM_NCDESTROY:
        RemoveWindowSubclass(hwnd, ButtonProc, uIdSubClass);
        break;
    }
    return DefSubclassProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
}

BOOL CALLBACK DlgProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp)
{
    if(msg == WM_INITDIALOG)
    {
        CreateWindow(L"EDIT", L"", 
            WS_TABSTOP | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER | ES_WANTRETURN, 
            5, 5, 200, 40, hwnd, HMENU(100), 0, 0);

        HWND bn1 = CreateWindow(L"BUTTON", L"Standard/Default",
            WS_TABSTOP | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON,
            5, 55 * 1, 200, 50, hwnd, HMENU(101), 0, 0);

        HWND bn2 = CreateWindow(L"BUTTON", L"OwnerDraw",
            WS_TABSTOP | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | BS_PUSHBUTTON | BS_OWNERDRAW,
            5, 55 * 2, 200, 50, hwnd, HMENU(102), 0, 0);

        HFONT hfont = (HFONT)SendMessage(hwnd, WM_GETFONT, 0, 0);
        SendMessage(bn1, WM_SETFONT, (WPARAM)hfont, 0);
        SendMessage(bn2, WM_SETFONT, (WPARAM)hfont, 0);
        SetWindowSubclass(bn2, ButtonProc, 101, 0);
        return 0;
    }

    if(msg == WM_DRAWITEM)
    {
        LPDRAWITEMSTRUCT di = (LPDRAWITEMSTRUCT)lp;
        HTHEME htheme = OpenThemeData(di->hwndItem, L"BUTTON");
        if(htheme)
        {
            UINT bm_getstate = (UINT)SendMessage(di->hwndItem, BM_GETSTATE, 0, 0);

            int state_id = PBS_NORMAL;

            if(!IsWindowEnabled(di->hwndItem))  
                state_id = PBS_DISABLED;

            if(bm_getstate & BST_PUSHED)
                state_id = PBS_PRESSED;

            if(bm_getstate & BST_FOCUS)
                state_id = PBS_DEFAULTED;

            RECT rc = di->rcItem;
            DrawThemeBackground(htheme, di->hDC, BP_PUSHBUTTON, state_id, &rc, NULL);
            DrawThemeText(htheme, di->hDC, BP_PUSHBUTTON, state_id, L"<OwnerDraw>", -1,
                DT_CENTER | DT_SINGLELINE | DT_VCENTER, 0, &rc);

            if(bm_getstate & BST_FOCUS && !(di->itemState & ODS_NOFOCUSRECT))
            {
                MARGINS margins;
                GetThemeMargins(htheme, di->hDC, BP_PUSHBUTTON, PBS_DEFAULTED,
                    TMT_CONTENTMARGINS, &rc, &margins);
                InflateRect(&rc, -margins.cxLeftWidth, -margins.cyTopHeight);
                DrawFocusRect(di->hDC, &rc);
            }

            CloseThemeData(htheme);
        }
    }

    if(msg == WM_COMMAND && wp == IDCANCEL)
        EndDialog(hwnd, wp);

    return FALSE;
}

int WINAPI wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE, LPTSTR, int)
{
    return (int)DialogBox(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_DIALOG1), 0, (DLGPROC)DlgProc);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, so I guess I can't use `BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON` when owner draw button is present, at least not without a lot of additional work.

Comment: Since Windows Vista, one can use [custom draw](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761847(v=vs.85).aspx) instead, which allows you to keep the `BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON` style because `BS_OWNERDRAW` is not required.